has anyone succeeded in building SQL agent on large database?
I'm trying to do a SQL agent to chat with large database, I have tried all small database but the problem my approach doesn't work on large database because I'm putting the whole database schema in the prompt to let the LLM to know the tables column names and relation between tables, I'm making my own custom SQL agent because I don't want to rely on Langchain to give me ready SQL agent, can anyone suggest how to approach this problem to only include tables schema for related user question.
